# AngularFire firestore get / snapshotchanges / valuechanges action on observable is not async?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Hi I am having a very strange behaviour.

I am iterating over some documents and setting some promises that when the documents are fetched the UI is updated.

However, while the promises are atomic, the firestore / AngularFire waits for all the promises.

Example:

```
 for (const event of events) {
        this.eventService.getEventActivitiesAndSomeStreams(this.user,
          event.getID(),
          [DataLatitudeDegrees.type, DataLongitudeDegrees.type])
          .pipe(take(1)).toPromise().then((fullEvent) => {
            this.logger.info(`Promise completed`)
           
          })
      }
```

One would expect that slowly for each promise as the data comes it would print the promise completed.

However they are all printed as once. It doesn't look that those promises come one by one but "all at once". There is a big waiting time till the first console log is printed and then all promises print that.

So I would expect if I have a progress bar to increase little but little but increases at once

The inner call `this.eventService.getEventActivitiesAndSomeStreams`

```
return this.afs
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('events')
        .doc(eventID)
        .collection('activities')
        .doc(activityID)
        .collection('streams', ((ref) => {
          return ref.where('type', 'in', typesBatch);
        }))
        .get()
        .pipe(map((documentSnapshots) => {
          return documentSnapshots.docs.reduce((streamArray: StreamInterface[], documentSnapshot) => {
            streamArray.push(this.processStreamDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot)); // Does nothing rather to create an class of the JSON object passed back from the firestore
            return streamArray;
          }, []);
        }))
```

Now, if I put an await inside the for loop of course this works as it should going and completing the promises as it should, but then it takes a lot of time.

I also tried to not use AngularFire and use the native JS SDK with the same effect.

I am suspecting that the IndexedDB can be causing this or some other Firebase logic.

What am I missing here, and how can I have the desired behaviour if possible?

You could repro this via a ["users" -> "events" -> "something"] firestore collections, were  each "user" has lets say 500 "events" and each of those events has 2 more docs.

So get all the events for the user and try to make for each one a promise that will return 2 documents of "something" inside a for array )

Comment: not sure if provided code is sufficient. Would you be able to share complete `getEventActivitiesAndSomeStreams` and `processStreamDocumentSnapshot` methods?

Comment: @DipenShah `processStreamDocumentSnapshot ` is just a JSON to class instance nothing more than instanciating an object from the JSON return. The `getEventActivitiesAndSomeStreams ` calls what I wrote above "basically", it just has the `collection` names etc that I hardcoded here

Comment: You could repro this via a "users" -> "events" -> "something"  where  each "user" has lets say 500 "events" and each of those events has 2 more docs. 

So get all the events for the user and try to make for each one a promise that will return 2 documents of "something" inside a for array

Comment: why would you expect things to iterate one by one here? You activate all of the streams in a for loop which will be near instantaneous to human perception and means they all make their requests at basically the same time, so they should get all of their responses at basically the same time. you have no async / await statements or other stream control tools telling it to do them one by one... if you put in any details about what you WANT to occur, then I can be of assistance, but as it stands, everything is behaving exactly as it should be expected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is pretty expected and has nothing at all to do with firebase. you're iterating over an array and sending out requests. there is no waiting or delay between items, so the for loop (without await statements) will finish in an imperceptibly small amount of time, which means all of the requests are being sent out within milliseconds of each other, or basically at the same time. So their responses should be expected to arrive at basically the same time as well.

You've stated that you don't want to use await statements and iterate one by one, so it's tough to know exactly what you do want or expect to happen. maybe you want them to be spaced .5 second apart? If so, you need to write that logic:

```
timer(0, 500).pipe( // put whatever ms time between requests you want here?
  take(events.length),
  switchMap(i => {
    return this.eventService.getEventActivitiesAndSomeStreams(this.user,
      events[i].getID(),
      [DataLatitudeDegrees.type, DataLongitudeDegrees.type]).pipe(take(1))
  })
).subscribe(fullEvent => {
  this.logger.info(`Promise completed`)
})
```

(removed promises cause idk why they're being used in the first place and this kind of control is easier with rxjs IMO)

Comment: hmmm but the problm is not finishing the loop. Is that all the "then" of the promises are fired at once with a Long waiting time.

Comment: that's how async programming works. the loop makes all the requests at basically the same time, then all of the requests come back at basically the same time, and the `then` handler runs whenever the response comes in. it doesn't care when or how it was sent. the "long waiting time" is just however long it takes for requests to be processed. if it's much quicker sending one or a few requests, then you're probably just putting strain on the browser with too many requests at once.

Comment: Yeah I know that but again. Imagine a progress bar of downloading files. Doesn't this mean that one of the promises , the one with the smallest size, would enter the "then" part first? 

Here all enter the "then" part pretty much at the same time. We are talking about 500*1Mb files (API reads) that all complete at once. 

Is that really by design? What did I miss?

Comment: in the case of file downloads where there was a significant variation in response times, then yes, you would see that. But in your case, all of the requests happen to take roughly the same amount of time. But, if you're making 500 requests at once, you're asking way too much of a browser tbh.

Comment: You might be right. Let me validate that with the network tab. Thanks

Comment: 500 requests at once also might just be causing a traffic jam as you're going to start running up against choke points in what the browser can handle. you may want to explore batching or preferably designing to NOT make that many requests at once. First solution that comes to mind is requesting list of events from the API rather than making a request for each individual event.

Comment: Yeah that was it. I validated that with wrapping with  an  increased timeout  each promise. 

The thing is that the firestore , has only one "connection" so you dont see this "parallel" behaviour in the network tab. 

Adding a timeout made that possible to be seen, I ll check how to improve this. 

Thank you